# C++ Initialize Class based global variables

Tags: c++

I am trying to define few global variables which should be available all functions but would like to initialize from main program. Can anyone help me with the syntax? Please note that still a bit beginner with c++ classes etc. As I need to run the same copy of this program multiple times and don't want to have a same shared class across multiple instances of this program - need to ensure I create a new class in the main body. Also wanted to mention - printvars - is a pre-built function for me and I don't have control over passing any pointer variables to it - just that I can only use global variables in that function.

```
class gvars
{
   public:
   int x=0;
   int y=0;
   gvars() {}
   ~gvars() {}
};

std::unique_ptr<gvars> *g=NULL;  // Must be a pointer to class

//I can't pass any parameters to this function
//Only have control over the body of the program to access global vars
void printvars()
{
   std::cout << (*g).x << " " << (*g).y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

  if (g==NULL)
  {
     g=new gvars();  // This is critical  - create a new class here only
  }

  (*g).x=10;
  (*g).y=20;

  printvars();  // Expected output :  10   20

  delete g;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're already using `std::unique_ptr`, why do you need a pointer to that, and why not use `nullptr`?

Comment: As @chris mentioned, you probably want to change to `std::unique_ptr<gvars> g=std::nullptr;`.

Comment: @chris C++11 hasnt quite caught on yet to the masses

Comment: @marc no, as in the keyword `std::unique_ptr<gvars> g = nullptr;`

Comment: @Need4Sleep I was correcting the use of `*g`, but yes, you're right; changed my comment.

Comment: Can anyone simplify this for me please? Main intention is to initialize a new class in main program and use them in other functions.

Comment: I don't even see why you need any sort of pointer at all. Just declare a global variable: `gvars g;` It will be constructed before main begins and destructed after main returns.

Comment: Or if you only need one copy of all the variables, just put them inside a namespace instead of a class.

Comment: Raymond - I need to run this program in parallel through same dll - and don't want to use same instance of these global variables across multiple instances of this program and is the reason for initializing new gvars in main section.

Comment: A function (main) cannot have any other function definitions inside, and we know that g is not seen by printvars(). So your choices are to make g global (outside of main), or set up printvars to receive gvars.

Comment: @C.Lang - Can you please elaborate a bit on this? Your suggestion is to have the line "gvars g;" above the printvars function? Won't it cause issues if multiple instances of this program is running - and each program needs to use it's own copy of variable?

Comment: @RaymondChen - Would give it a try and see if there are any issues I run into.. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work in my case moving "gvars g;" prior to printvars - section - it works fine for a single run of the program but when run multiple instances of the same using same DLL - there is an overlap. Any further suggestions on using a pointer and initializing it in the main section?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances of the same using same DLL"? Multiple instances of a program have separate copies of global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is good except only line.
Try change

```
std::unique_ptr<gvars> *g=NULL;  // Must be a pointer to class
```

to

```
gvars*g=NULL;
```

Program will create/delete new instance of your class on each run for sure. Also `printvars` should work fine.

Comment: Nikolay - Thanks for the correction. On related - does "delete g" in the main program appropriate?

Comment: @ejuser Yes, that's a good style - delete memory allocated by your program. Though g object will be destructed and deallocated implicitly as program exits. So without `delete g;` statement program still be correct but code analyze tools like valgrind may warn you about possible memory leak.